# Trying to enable swipe to left.html or right.html

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

There are three pages index.html and right.html and left.html

```
$.mobile.loadPage( "right.html" ).loadPage( "left.html" );  // for page prefetching 

$(document).on( "swiperight" ,  function( ) 
                                   {
    $.mobile.changePage( "right.html", { transition: "slide" , reverse: true } );
                                   }                
                );


$(document).on( "swipeleft" ,   function( ) 
                                   {
    $.mobile.changePage( "left.html", { transition: "slide" , reverse: true } );
                                   }

                );
```

And if I replace

```
 $.mobile.changePage( "left.html", { transition: "slide" , reverse: true } );
```

with

```
 alert("swipeleft");
```

It does show me an alert window that says "swipeleft"

Then is the following code correct?

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "left.html");
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "right.html");


// Enabling Swype

$(document).on( "swiperight" ,  function( ) 
                            {

$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "right.html", { transition: "slide" , reverse: true } );

                            }

                            );

$(document).on( "swipeleft" ,   function( ) 
                            {

$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "left.html", { transition: "slide" , reverse: true } );

                            }

                            );
```

By the way, the directory goes like this

the above source code is saved inside a directory called js and at the same level as the js folder, there are the three html files

Then does it have to be "../left.html" instead of "left.html"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which version of JQM are you using?

Comment: I am using jQu Mo 1.4.3

Comment: `.loadPage` is deprecated, use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page.html");`. To change pages, same previous function but `("change", "page.html", { transition: "whatever"});`.

Comment: Then is the above correct?

Comment: The above is correct and should work. Are you getting any errors? Can you see pages loaded in DOM?